# In graph theory, what is a "common cycle"?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I've come across this theorem and I don't understand a definition used in it:

> A graph of order at least $3$ is nonseparable iff every two vertices lie on a common cycle

What's a common cycle?  Is it two cycles in a graph that share an edge or a point?  Or is this just saying that they lie on the same cycle?

Comment: It's just saying that they lie on the same cycle. Note, however, this is different from saying that *every* pair lies on *the same cycle*.

Comment: In the definition you quoted, the word "common" is not a technical term; it is used in its ordinary English meaning. Should we correct the misspelling of "vertices" or was it misspelled "verticies" in the unnamed source that you are quoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just means that for any vertices $v$ and $w$, there exists a cycle $C$ which contains both $v$ and $w$.  The word "common" is informal and merely emphasizes that this cycle $C$ depends on $v$ and $w$ and is shared by both of them (you could say that being in $C$ is a property that is common to $v$ and $w$).